# Grails. Domain class. Method AddTo*?

Tags: json, grails

I have this example:

```
def mycreate = {

    def id = params.id;
    def data = JSON.parse(params.data);

    def credit = Credit.get(id);

    def front = new Front ();
    front.properties = data;

    credit.addToFronts(front).save()

    render (front as JSON)
}
```

This action returns something like this:

```
{"class":"test.Front","id":null,"credits":{"class":"Credit","id":1},"dateCreated":null,"description":"write text here."}
```

But, for me, the params "`id`" and "`dateCreated`" are `null`. How can I get the values of these params?

Comment: it'd be easier to help if you also posted your Front and Credit domain objects (in case you haven't defined things correctly there).  Is it possible that the credit isn't actually getting saved?  You aren't checking to see if there are errors.  What happens if you change the save to save(failOnError: true)?  Does it blow up with any domain exceptions?

Comment: it's very funny, but it works. I only added the parameter flush: true in method save()

Comment: that's obvious, db persisting does not occur on save(), this just marks the object as to-be-saved on flushing. Flushing is the action that performs persitence and therefore populates id and dateCreated.